# Remove SVN from an existing Java project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have a versioned Java project in Eclipse.

I decided to remove "SVN" so that when I `right-click > Team` on the project, I can only obtain the following choices : `Share project ...` and `Create patch ...` instead of `commit ...`, `Update`, etc.

What is the best (cleanest) method to remove version control from a project in Eclipse ?

Comment: How about deleting the `.svn` folders and restarting Eclipse?

Answer (score 22):

If your project is properly version controlled with SVN, you should be able to see "Synchronize with Repository", "Commit", "Update" under the "Team" menu item of the context menu. In this case, you can use `Team > Disconnect`.

If you can't see the menu items like these under Team menu, check that there is `.svn` (hidden) directory in your project root.

Perhaps you can check out the project again from the repository and use `Team > Disconnect` if you haven't changed the code a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Try to recursively delete all .svn folders from your project's root folder. For example, on a Linux machine, you should issue the following command in the project's root folder:

rm -rf `find . -type d -name .svn`

Answer (score 1):

You only have to remove the top level .svn folder. Then share the project and Eclipse is smart enough to delete all the recursive .svn folders.

Answer (score 0):

One good approach to export the SVN project from the repository instead of a checkout which will not have the .svn folders, the local workspace can then be used for updating into a different branch or repository with a similar folder structure.

```
svn export [-r REV] URL[@PEGREV] [PATH]

Eg : http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the .svn folders in your project by:

1. Open Terminal
2. cd "Your project path"
3. find . -type d -name .svn -depth -exec rm -rf {} \;

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution :

Find the `.svn` folder in your project directory. It is a hidden folder so find it from `File-> show hidden folder`. Then delete it .